# CDS Association with where condition containing a SELECT

Tags: abap, cds

I have two views :

ZC_PurRequisitionFs and ZMM_ONAYT005.

First view extended from C_PurRequisitionFs.

Second view gets data from Z* table.

How can I get only first view data that does not exist on second view ?

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewAppendName: 'ZCPURREQUISFS'
@EndUserText.label: 'Sat belgeleri'
extend view C_PurRequisitionFs with ZC_PurRequisitionFs {
    *
} where ZC_PurRequisitionFs.object_id not in( SELECT * FROM ZMM_ONAYT005 ).
```

Comment: so this piece you gave does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While CDS views do not support subqueries, they do support JOINs.

Usually you would use a JOIN to get only those entries which exist in both tables. But when you want all entries from table A which **don't** exist in table B, you can do a `left outer join` and then add a `where`-condition for only entries where the right table `is null`.

```
define view Z_TEST as select 
from table_a
left outer join table_b on 
    table_a.object_id = table_b.object_id
{
    ... fields....
}
where table_b.object_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ABAP CDS view does not support subqueries, so you would need to include it in the main query.

Please check this [guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/08/not-exists-subqueries-in-abap-cds-views/).